# How do I avoid MDIParent form from resizing

Tags: winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I am designing a Windows Form app. I have an MDIParent form that loads in a maximized state, and loads its child forms in a maximized state as well. However, when I open an OpenFileDialog, or any datareader object, the MDIParent shrinks to a smaller size with all its forms and controls.

This solution [Opening child form is causing mdiform to change size and shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452774/opening-child-form-is-causing-mdiform-to-change-size-and-shrink) does not apply/work in my situation.

Also this solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/967173/restoring-a-maximized-or-minimized-mdi-parent-form-causes-its-height-t did not work for me.

Some background: I have seen this behaviour in almost all my WinForm applications but I have never been keen to sort it out. I was able to narrow down to the causes as highlighted above when I started investigate it. Some posts are describing it as a windows bug, but it has existed for as long as the screen resolutions started going above 1024 (VS 2010) for my case. I hoped it is not just a windows bug...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I hoped it is not just a windows bug...

Feature, not a bug, but it is not one that Winforms programmers like very much.  Notable is that there have been several questions about mystifying window shrinkage in the past few months.  I *think* it is associated with the release of Win10 Fall Creators edition.  It has deep changes to the legacy Win32 api layer and they've caused plenty of upheaval.

In your specific case, the "feature" is enabled by a shell extension.  They get injected into your process when you use OpenFileDialog.  The one that does this is very, very evil and does something that a shell extension must absolutely never do.  It calls [SetProcessDPIAware()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543(v=vs.85).aspx).  Notable is that it might have been written in WPF, it has a very sneaky backdoor to declare itself dpiAware.  Just loading the PresentationCore assembly is enough.  But not otherwise limited to WPF code, any code can do this and that might have been undetected for a long time.

One way to chase down this evil extension is by using SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.  It lets you selectively disable extensions.  But there is also a programmer's way, you can debug this in VS.

Use Project > Properties > Debug tab > tick the "Enable native code debugging" checkbox.  Named slightly different in old VS versions btw.  Then Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint.  Function name = `user32!SetProcessDPIAware`, Language = `C`.  You can exercise this in a do-nothing WPF app to ensure that everything is set correctly.  For completeness you can also add the breakpoint for SetProcessDPIAwareness, the new flavor.

Press F5 to start debugging and trigger the OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() call.  The breakpoint should now hit, use Debug > Windows > Call Stack to look at the stack trace.  You typically will not see anything very recognizable in your case since the evil code lives in a DLL that you don't have a PDB for.  But the DLL name and location (visible in Debug > Windows > Modules) ought to be helpful to identify the person you need to file a bug with.  Uninstall it if you can live without it.

Last but not least, it is getting pretty important to start creating Winforms apps that are dpiAware so such a bug can never byte.  You kick this off by [declaring your app to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) so DPI virtualization is disabled.  Plus whatever you need to do in your code to ensure the UI design scales properly.

Comment: Thank you Hans for the explanations. I followed your steps but I was however getting lost in the Modules... I have not idea which file it is I am supposed to delete/uninstall out of the list of about 100 dlls?

Comment: 100, ouch.  That is why I recommended using the debugger.  You can still tackle 100 by disabling half of them repeatedly.  50, 25, 13, 7, 4, 2, 1, only 7 tries max to find the evil-doer.  Binary search to solve a computer problem, hehe.

Comment: HOWEVER, then manifest answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e/13228495#13228495 that you pointed me to solved it!